# Batch file for replace characters in all CSV of a folder

Tags: csv, batch-file

I have a batch file which goes through a specific CSV file (line-by-ine) and at first  replaces each comma by a semicolon and then each dot by a comma.
How to optimize this batch file, so it cycles automatically through every CSV file within the folder, where also the batch file is located?

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

    (for /f "tokens=*" %%f in (a.csv) do if not "%%f"=="" (
            set "line=%%f"
            set "line=!line:,=;!"
            set "line=!line:.=,!"
            echo(!line!
    )) > b.csv

    endlocal
```

More over no new CSV should be generated by the batch file. The original CSV files should simply be overwritten.

Thanks alot!

Comment: Wrap a standard `for %%i in (*.csv) do` loop around and use `%%~i` rather than the constant `a.csv`. for the output file `b.csv`, think of something like `%%~ni.new`, so no naming conflicts with the source files can arise...

Comment: You do not need the `IF` comparison.  The for variable will only be populated if there is data assigned to it.  You will need to output the file to a temporary file and then delete the original  and rename the temporary file to the original file.

Comment: On a standard Windows system, the basic batch file commands cannot open, read, modify and write to the same file. If you require that functionality you'll need to utilise another language, e.g. jscript, vbscript, powershell. Once you've decided upon the language you wish to utilise, write your code and update your question, remembering to add the appropriate tag for your chosen language.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I found  with the help of `aschipfl`s comment:

> Wrap a standard for %%i in (*.csv) do loop around and use %%~i rather
>   than the constant a.csv. for the output file b.csv, think of something
>   like %%~ni.new, so no naming conflicts with the source files can
>   arise...

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

    (for %%i in (*.csv) do (

        (for /f "tokens=*" %%f in (%%~i) do if not "%%f"=="" (
                set "line=%%f"
                set "line=!line:,=;!"
                set "line=!line:.=,!"
                echo !line! 
        )) > %%~ni_FIX.csv
    ))

    endlocal
```

Comment: On NTFS volumes this will work, On FAT Family volumes this will stuck in the loop filling your disk with `FileName_FIX.csv` , `FileName_FIX_FIX.csv`, `FileName_FIX_FIX_FIX.csv`,... Instead choose another extension for the new files then do a rename. In the loop: `>"%%~ni_FIX.~csv"` (don't forget to enclose the file name in quotes) and at the end after the processing all `csv` files finished do `ren *.~csv *.csv`

Comment: And the `for /f` should be written like this: `for /f "usebackq delims=" %%f in ("%%~i") do ...` enclose `%%~i` in quotes, and I suggest you to replace `"tokens=*` by `"delims="` (which `tokens=1` is implicit), That way there would be no need to check for empty token on each iteration, as the `FOR` command will not call the body of loop when the first **numbered** token is empty.